# Azure Partner Center Sdk Get Granular Historical Billing Information

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-billing-api

This [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/partnercenter/mt735170.aspx) describes the SubscriptionDailyUsage Resource, which is obsolete, and suggests using the Utilization resource (which offers very granular utilization data) and marrying it to an [IAzureRateCard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/partnercenter/microsoft.store.partnercenter.ratecards.get.aspx) which offers real time azure pricing.  I've looked at the [UsageRecords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/partnercenter/mt219213.aspx) resource but it isn't granular enough, and [ServiceCosts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/partnercenter/mt798163.aspx) both isn't granular enough and is only available for the previous month.

Is there any way to get an azure rate card for a previous time period, or any other way to get granular historic pricing data?

Comment: The azure rate card api doesn't support directly get the previous time period records. It doesn't has the datetime filter. Details, you could see this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt219004.aspx#Response). If you want to use this api, you need firstly get the record then select the useful information by yourself or use some tool like [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-usage-rate-card-partner-solution-cloudyn). I suggest you could try to use [Enterprise Reporting API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-enterprise-api).

Comment: those both look very promising.  I'm not sure if we have access to the Enterprise Reporting API, but I will look into it